# killbill connection timeout from symfony in docker

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose, symfony4, killbill

I have implemented killbill service in docker as following:

```
killbill:
    image: killbill/killbill:0.18.11
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8087:8080"
      - "12345:12345"
    links:
      - killbilldb
      - nginx
    environment:
      - KILLBILL_CONFIG_DAO_URL=jdbc:mysql://killbilldb:3306/killbill
      - KILLBILL_CONFIG_DAO_USER=root
      - KILLBILL_CONFIG_DAO_PASSWORD=killbill
      - STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY=${STRIPE_API_SECRET_KEY:-abcd}
      - STRIPE_API_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=${STRIPE_API_PUBLISHABLE_KEY:-1234}
  kaui:
    image: killbill/kaui:0.8.8
    links:
      - killbilldb
      - killbill
    environment:
      - KAUI_CONFIG_DAO_URL=jdbc:mysql://killbilldb:3306/kaui
      - KAUI_CONFIG_DAO_USER=root
      - KAUI_CONFIG_DAO_PASSWORD=killbill
      - KAUI_KILLBILL_URL=http://killbill:8080
      - KAUI_KILLBILL_API_KEY=bob
      - KAUI_KILLBILL_API_SECRET=lazar
    ports: 
      - "9090:8080"
  killbilldb:
    image: registry.champs-libres.be/comedien/killbilldb:${version:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./killbilldb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=killbill
```

While checking from symfony killbill throws an exception of timeout after few minutes.

I have uploaded an image of error. So you can check exception.[image]

So if you have any idea then let me know.

Comment: Can you try and add ENV_HOST_IP to the environment variables of killbill? The value should be the IP of your host.